# Exception in Tkinter Callback fix?

Tags: python, mongodb, tkinter

i am using Tkinter as a gui for a desktop application i am creating. i keep getting the same error

```
from tkinter import Tk
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import schedule
import time
from Tweets import Tweets


class MyFirstGUI:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def masterframe(self, master, ):

        master = master
        master.title("A simple Sentiment Analyzer")

        _bgcolor = '#4285F4'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#e3f2fd'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec'  # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'
        style = ttk.Style()

        if sys.platform == "win32":
            style.theme_use('winnative')

            style.configure('.', background=_bgcolor)

            style.configure('.', foreground=_fgcolor)

            style.configure('.', font="Arial")

            style.map('.', background=[('selected', _compcolor), ('active', _ana2color)])

        master.geometry("600x450+650+150")

        master.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        return master

    def appframe(self, master):

        tFrame1 = ttk.Frame(master)
        tFrame1.place(relx=-0.017, rely=-0.067, relheight=1.078, relwidth=1.025)
        tFrame1.configure(relief='groove')
        tFrame1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        tFrame1.configure(relief="groove")
        tFrame1.configure(width=615)
        return tFrame1

    def headerlabel(self, tframe1):
        headind_label = tk.Label(tframe1)
        headind_label.place(relx=0.049, rely=0.165, height=21, width=294)
        headind_label.configure(background="#4285F4")
        headind_label.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        headind_label.configure(foreground="#ffffff")
        headind_label.configure(text='''Enter Keyword/Hashtag from Twitter''', font=("Helvetica Bold", 12))

    def keywordlabel(self, tframe1):
        key_label = tk.Label(tframe1)
        key_label.place(relx=0.081, rely=0.268, height=31, width=94)
        key_label.configure(background="#4285F4")
        key_label.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        key_label.configure(foreground="#ffffff")
        key_label.configure(text='''Keyword''', font=("Helvetica Bold", 9))
        key_label.configure(width=94)

    def timeselection(self, tframe1):
        time_label = tk.Label(tframe1)
        time_label.place(relx=0.049, rely=0.392, height=31, width=134)
        time_label.configure(background="#4285F4")
        time_label.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        time_label.configure(foreground="#ffffff")
        time_label.configure(text='''Run time(hourly)''', font=("Helvetica Bold", 9))
        time_label.configure(width=114)

    def keyword_input(self, tframe1, ):

        global key_input
        key_input = tk.Entry(tframe1)
        key_input.place(relx=0.276, rely=0.268, height=30, relwidth=0.234)
        key_input.configure(background="white")
        key_input.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        key_input.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        key_input.configure(foreground="#000000")
        key_input.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        key_input.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        key_input.configure(insertbackground="black")
        key_input.configure(selectbackground="#c4c4c4")
        key_input.configure(selectforeground="black")


    def startbutton(self, tframe1):
        start_Button = tk.Button(tframe1)
        start_Button.place(relx=0.293, rely=0.515, height=24, width=35)
        start_Button.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        start_Button.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        start_Button.configure(background="#ffffff")
        start_Button.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        start_Button.configure(foreground="#000000")
        start_Button.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        start_Button.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        start_Button.configure(pady="0")
        start_Button.configure(text='''Start''', command=self.runjob)

    def stopbutton(self, tframe1):
        stop_button = tk.Button(tframe1)
        stop_button.place(relx=0.407, rely=0.515, height=24, width=35)
        stop_button.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        stop_button.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        stop_button.configure(background="#ffffff")
        stop_button.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        stop_button.configure(foreground="#000000")
        stop_button.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        stop_button.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        stop_button.configure(pady="0")
        stop_button.configure(text='''Stop''', command=self.stopjob)

    def combobox(self, tframe1):
        global time_selection
        time_selection = ttk.Combobox(tframe1)
        time_selection.place(relx=0.276, rely=0.392, relheight=0.064, relwidth=0.233)
        time_selection['values'] = ("1", "6", "12", "24")
        time_selection.current(0)  # set the selected item
        time_selection.configure(takefocus="")

    def frame_divider(self, tframe1):
        tseparator1 = ttk.Separator(tframe1)
        tseparator1.place(relx=0.545, rely=0.01, relheight=0.99)
        tseparator1.configure(orient="vertical")

    def job_get_tweet(self):
        # api-endpoint
        base_url = "http://192.168.0.7/"
        tweet_word = key_input.get()
        tweet = Tweets()
        tweet.retrieve_tweet(base_url, tweet_word)

    def job_fetch_tweet_from_db(self):
        # api-endpoint
        base_url = "http://192.168.0.7/"
        tweet_get = Tweets()
        tweet_get.get_tweet_from_db(base_url)

    def runjob(self, ):
        messagebox.showinfo('Tweet Scheduler', 'Tweet has been scheduled to run ' + time_selection.get() + ' hours')
        schedule.every(int(time_selection.get())).hour.do(self.job_get_tweet())
        # schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job_fetch_tweet_from_db)
        # schedule.every( ).day.at("10:30").do(job)
        # schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
        # schedule.every( ).monday.do(job)
        # schedule.every( ).wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
        # schedule.every( ).minute.at(":17").do(job)
        running = True
        while running:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

    def stopjob(self):
        print('job stopped')


root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI()
username = tk.StringVar()

# calling the master frame method to create the master window
master_frame = my_gui.masterframe(root)

# calling the application frame to pack all widgets
app_frame = my_gui.appframe(master_frame)

# calling the first label widget method to display the label
my_gui.headerlabel(app_frame)

# calling the keyword label method to display the label widget
my_gui.keywordlabel(app_frame)

# calling the time selection label method to display the label widget
my_gui.timeselection(app_frame)

# calling the text entry widget in the frame
my_gui.keyword_input(app_frame)

# calling the timeslot selection widget in the frame
my_gui.combobox(app_frame)

# calling the start button widget to fire an action
my_gui.startbutton(app_frame)

# calling the stop button widget to fire an action to stop all running instances
my_gui.stopbutton(app_frame)

# calling frame vertical seperator
my_gui.frame_divider(app_frame)

# displays all widgets used fro the tkinter library
root.mainloop()
```

i am expecting the tweets to be saved in my mongodb database but keep getting

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cybor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code that is not directly related to the question being asked.